# How to get the get the total number of items in a single G Suite API query?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am developing a simple app to consume data from some G Suite APIs (*Admin SDK*, *Drive*, *Gmail*, etc.).

G Suite API endpoints allowing the `list` method (for collections) provide queries with a response of the following kind (content may vary from API to API):

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#users",
  "etag": "\"WczyXiapC9UmAQ6oKabcde6P59w-7argQ83zwDwKoUE/zsH-hyZTP1lFsB3-wabK4_8VXMk\"",
  "users": [
    {
      "kind": "admin#directory#user",
      "id": "137674315191655104007",
      "etag": "\"WczyXiapC9..."
      ...
    },
        ... 
    # N elements of type 'user', where N <= maxResults,
    # being <maxResults>, the maximum number of elements in the response per query.
    # <maxResults> has a system default value.
    ]
}
```

In order to get the total number of available elements for consumption in that API, I may encounter the following cases:

1. One single query if the total number of available elements is less or equal than `maxResults`.
2. More than one if the total number of available elements is greater than `maxResults`.

When number two occurs, the G Suite API returns a pagination token which I will use in successive queries to retrieve more pages with up to `maxResults` elements.

Once I have consumed all the elements I can get the total number.

My question is:

**Is it possible, to retrieve the total number of elements (just the integer value) in the query with a single API call and thus, avoid pagination?**

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Is it possible, to retrieve the total number of elements (just the integer value) in the query with a single API call and thus, avoid pagination?

if a method contains a parameter called MaxResults that is because it has a maximum number of rows that a call can return.

If you look at the documentation for the Google drive api file.list method

> The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)

This means that it can return to you a maximum of 1000 files then you will need to paginate.  There is no way around this limitation in the api.